# How can I save string to a variable in assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I mean if I can save it in data section, like here:

```
.data
    str:    .asciiz    "abc"
.text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str
    syscall
```

How it's possible to put string "abc" to the *str* variable or override it by another string in text section?

Answer (score 0):

About putting the “abc” string to the str variable. Actually the str variable is the address of the first index of the string, so it already “have” the string abc.

About overwrite it with another string.
First the new string size must be the same or smaller than the original one.
Then, since i don’t know witch assembly you’re using, i will just explain who it would work:

You would need to get the str value ( the address of the string), and then move character by character to the *str* space of memory.

This happens because str is not really a variable, it’s actually a label, a nick name to some memory address. So you cannot make it point to another string.